# Is it possible to change output to show duplicates once followed by a number indicating occurences

Tags: c++, vector, duplicates

Very new to programming, im making a simple shopping list planner which organises ingrediants in order of appearence in the shop.
I have the following output:
Heres what you need:
Bataati
Brocoli
Turnip
Carrot
Cherry toms
Beef
Beef
Chicken
Chicken
Lohi
Creme Fraiche
Eggs
Kermaviili
Cheese
Tomaatti Murska
Macaroni
Macaroni
Ready Chicken

But i would like:
Heres what you need:
Bataati
Brocoli
Turnip
Carrot
Cherry toms
Beef *2
Chicken *2
Lohi
Creme Fraiche
Eggs
Kermaviili
Cheese
Tomaatti Murska
Macaroni *2

Is this in any way possible?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

main() {
    char aWord[20];
    std::vector<std::string> Vege {};
    std::vector<std::string> Meat {};
    std::vector<std::string> Eines {};
    std::vector<std::string> Milk {};
    std::vector<std::string> Bread {};
    std::vector<std::string> Cheese {};
    std::vector<std::string> Preservative {};
    std::vector<std::string> Pasta {};
    std::vector<std::string> Texmex {};
    std::vector<std::string> Frozen {};
    std::vector<std::string> Actualshoppinglist {"Heres what you need:"};


    std::ifstream file("Shoppinglist.txt");

    while (file.good()) {
    file>>aWord;
    if (file.good() && strcmp(aWord, "Tortillat") == 0) {
        Meat.push_back("Beef");
        Vege.push_back("Salad\nCucumber\nTomato");
        Texmex.push_back("Tortilla wraps\nSalsa");
    } else if (file.good() && strcmp(aWord, "Chicken_Soup") == 0) {
        Meat.push_back("Chicken");
        Milk.push_back("Creme Fraiche");
        Frozen.push_back("Keittojuures");
    } else if (file.good() && strcmp(aWord, "Mexican_pata") == 0) {
        Meat.push_back("Beef");
        Preservative.push_back("Tomaatti murska");
        Pasta.push_back("Raketti Spaghetti");
    } else if (file.good() && strcmp(aWord, "Lasagne") == 0) {
        Meat.push_back("Beef");
        Preservative.push_back("Tomaatti Murska");
        Cheese.push_back("Cheese");
        Vege.push_back("Carrot");
    } else if (file.good() && strcmp(aWord, "Macaroni_laattiko") == 0) {
        Meat.push_back("Beef");
        Milk.push_back("Eggs");
        Pasta.push_back("Macaroni");
    } else if (file.good() && strcmp(aWord, "Chicken_Breasts") == 0) {
        Meat.push_back("Chicken");
        Vege.push_back("Bataati\nBrocoli\nTurnip");
        Frozen.push_back("Keittojuures");
    } else if (file.good() && strcmp(aWord, "Chicken_Sauce") == 0) {
        Meat.push_back("Chicken");
        Vege.push_back("Brocoli");
        Pasta.push_back("Pasta");
        Milk.push_back("Cream");
    } else if (file.good() && strcmp(aWord, "Chicken_Tortilla") == 0) {
        Meat.push_back("Chicken");
        Vege.push_back("Salad\nCucumber\nTomato");
        Texmex.push_back("Salsa");
        Preservative.push_back("Pineapple");
    } else if (file.good() && strcmp(aWord, "Fishfingers_and_mash") == 0) {
        Frozen.push_back("Fishfingers\nPeas");
        Milk.push_back("Kermaviili");
    } else if (file.good() && strcmp(aWord, "Lohi_Medaljonki") == 0) {
        Eines.push_back("Lohi");
        Vege.push_back("Cherry toms");
        Milk.push_back("Kermaviili");
    } else if (file.good() && strcmp(aWord, "Tuna pasta") == 0) {
        Milk.push_back("Cream");
        Preservative.push_back("Tuna");
        Pasta.push_back("Pasta");
    } else if (file.good() && strcmp(aWord, "Ready_chicken_food") == 0) {
        Frozen.push_back("Ready Chicken");
    } else if (file.good() && strcmp(aWord, "Chilicon") == 0) {
        Preservative.push_back("Tomaatti murska\nBean mix");
        Pasta.push_back("Rice");
        
    } else {
        std::cout << "";
    }

}

    std::sort(Meat.begin(), Meat.end());
    std::sort(Vege.begin(), Vege.end());
    std::sort(Eines.begin(), Eines.end());
    std::sort(Milk.begin(), Milk.end());
    std::sort(Bread.begin(), Bread.end());
    std::sort(Cheese.begin(), Cheese.end());
    std::sort(Preservative.begin(), Preservative.end());
    std::sort(Pasta.begin(), Pasta.end());
    std::sort(Texmex.begin(), Texmex.end());
    std::sort(Frozen.begin(), Frozen.end());
    Actualshoppinglist.insert( Actualshoppinglist.end(), Vege.begin(), Vege.end() );
    Actualshoppinglist.insert( Actualshoppinglist.end(), Meat.begin(), Meat.end() );
    Actualshoppinglist.insert( Actualshoppinglist.end(), Eines.begin(), Eines.end() );
    Actualshoppinglist.insert( Actualshoppinglist.end(), Milk.begin(), Milk.end() );
    Actualshoppinglist.insert( Actualshoppinglist.end(), Bread.begin(), Bread.end() );
    Actualshoppinglist.insert( Actualshoppinglist.end(), Cheese.begin(), Cheese.end() );
    Actualshoppinglist.insert( Actualshoppinglist.end(), Preservative.begin(), Preservative.end() );
    Actualshoppinglist.insert( Actualshoppinglist.end(), Pasta.begin(), Pasta.end() );
    Actualshoppinglist.insert( Actualshoppinglist.end(), Texmex.begin(), Texmex.end() );
    Actualshoppinglist.insert( Actualshoppinglist.end(), Frozen.begin(), Frozen.end() );

    std::ofstream file_out("ActualShoppinglist.txt");
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < Actualshoppinglist.size(); ++i)
    file_out << Actualshoppinglist[i] << std::endl; 

}
```

Comment: Use a `std::map<std::string, int>`. Store the name of the ingredient as the key and the number of items at the value. `some_map["beef"]++` Then you can iterate through the map and print the quantity if the value is larger than 1.

Comment: You're overcomplicating the reading. Say `while (file >> aWord)` and you don't need to mess with `good()` at all. Also, use `std::string aWord;` and `==`.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, using a separate vector for every type of food is just causing problems. You're better off storing your lists in a `std::map`:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> items;
```

Now you can do:

```
items["Meat"].push_back("Beef");
items["Vege"].push_back("Salad");
items["Vege"].push_back("Cucumber");
items["Vege"].push_back("Tomato");
items["Texmex"].push_back("Tortilla wraps");
items["Texmex"].push_back("Salsa");
```

But why stop there?  See how we're repeating "Vege" creating a bug waiting to happen (due to typing errors) or generally creating a maintenance problem.  You can solve that with an enum:

```
enum Category {
    Vege,
    Meat,
    Eines,
    Milk,
    Bread,
    Cheese,
    Preservative,
    Pasta,
    Texmex,
    Frozen,
};

std::map<Category, std::vector<std::string>> items;
items[Meat].push_back("Beef");
items[Vege].push_back("Salad");
items[Vege].push_back("Cucumber");
items[Vege].push_back("Tomato");
items[Texmex].push_back("Tortilla wraps");
items[Texmex].push_back("Salsa");
```

That makes things a bit cleaner.  And you can create the full shopping list like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> shoppingList;
for (const auto& sublist : items) {
    shoppingList.insert(shoppingList.end(), sublist.begin(), sublist.end());
}
```

Now, what about the counts?  Well one way is you also turn your sub-lists into a `std::map` with the item name as a string, and then a count as the data:

```
std::map<Category, std::map<std::string, int>> items;
```

With the above, you can add an item one or more times by just counting:

```
items[Meat]["Beef"]++;
items[Meat]["Beef"]++;
```

Or:

```
items[Meat]["Beef"] += 10;  // need lots of beef!
```

You may even want to make a function:

```
void Add(std::map<Category, std::map<std::string, int>>& items,
         Category category, const std::string& item, int count = 1)
{
    items[category][name] += count;
}
```

And use it like:

```
Add(items, Meat, "Beef");
Add(items, Vege, "Perilla Leaves", 100000);
```

This changes your full shopping list generation a bit:

```
std::vector<std::string> shoppingList;
for (const auto& sublist : items) {
    for (const auto& entry : sublist) {
        const std::string& name = entry.first;
        int count = entry.second;

        if (count == 1) {
            // Add single item
            shoppingList.push_back(name);
        } else {
            // Add item with its count
            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << name << " *" << count;
            shoppingList.push_back(oss.str());
        }
    }
}
```

There is a side-effect of storing items in a map, which is that maps are ordered.  So your items in a sublist will be sorted alphabetically.

If you don't want that, then you'll need to store them in the original vectors one or more times, create a temporary map that counts everything in the vector, then walks through the vector.  You add only items from the map that have a non-zero count, and then after adding that item you set its count to zero to prevent it being re-added.  This is all a bit more hassle, but if you really want to then go ahead -- it's a good exercise for you to try.

Comment: Wow, this is the stuff which has got me interested in coding. Thanks for taking the time to help! Ill try some of that stuff and see how it starts looking. im not familiar with enum does it require a header?

Comment: No, `enum` is a keyword that defines an enumerated type -- basically a named integer value.  You'll need a header for `ostringstream` though (`<sstream>`)